# XStream: null out fields not mentioned in XML during in-place unmarshal

Tags: java, null, xstream

My project uses XStream for serialization and must sometimes use the two-argument form of `unmarshal` that deserializes data into an *existing* root object.

Normally this works fine. The [problem](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21017) comes when an object initially has a non-`null` field value, and you are loading data which does not mention that field at all (perhaps because it was producing by marshaling a different object of the same class in which that field was null). After in-place unmarshaling, the field is still set. For example,

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
public class Demo {
    static class Data {
        final String alpha;
        final String bravo;
        Data(String alpha, String bravo) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            this.bravo = bravo;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data d1 = new Data("one", "set");
        Data d2 = new Data("two", null);
        System.out.println(marshal(d1));
        System.out.println(marshal(d2));
        unmarshal(marshal(d2), d1);
        System.out.println(marshal(d1));
    }
    static XStream xs = new XStream();
    static XppDriver driver = new XppDriver();
    static String marshal(Object o) {
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        xs.marshal(o, driver.createWriter(w));
        return w.toString();
    }
    static void unmarshal(String data, Object o) {
        xs.unmarshal(driver.createReader(new StringReader(data)), o);
    }
}
```

prints

```
<Demo_-Data>
  <alpha>one</alpha>
  <bravo>set</bravo>
</Demo_-Data>
<Demo_-Data>
  <alpha>two</alpha>
</Demo_-Data>
<Demo_-Data>
  <alpha>two</alpha>
  <bravo>set</bravo>
</Demo_-Data>
```

since `d1.bravo` is not cleared.

Is there a way to instruct the `unmarshal` method to unset all fields which are not explicitly mentioned in the input, so that in this case `d1` would be made equal to `d2`?

Failing that, is there something that can be placed in the input specifically requesting a particular field to be unset? I tried both `<bravo/>` and `<bravo><null/></bravo>` without success—the `bravo` field is in both cases set to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jörg Schaible on the user list:

> XStream always sets only the elements that are present in XML. The fields of 
>   uninitialized objects are always null. There is no code in XStream to 
>   uninitialize fields if you provide an existing object as root. The only 
>   alternative is currently a custom converter.